# SAGA Gaussian Filter Results Stretched

Tags: raster, saga, generalization

New to a lot of these tools, so it's possible that I'm simply misunderstanding how to use them.

I have a world raster of population data (1px=1km) that I'm trying to generalize (It's for children so details aren't as important). When I run the Gaussian Blur filter in SAGA GUI, the results always appear stretched along the latitudes. It really doesn't matter what values I input for standard dev or kernel radius, there is always some sort of stretching involved.

Thinking it might have been the latitude of the subject area, I ran the filter in a region along the equator, and the stretching remained.

Some images below to illustrate, but is this even the right tool for the job? The goal is to generalize and then classify in large chunks.

[image: Midwest]

[image: South America]